# preg_match PHP pattern search for tokens

Tags: php, format, token, preg-match, fixed

Actually I am searching a string for specific tokens which follow a pattern @@text@@ and want to retrieve the tokens from that string into a new array:

> my address is @@address@@ and my house is at @@street@@ and the number is  @@number@@

I want  the tokens in that sentence as an array:

```
array[0] = @@address@@
array[1] = @@street@@
array[2] = @@number@@
        $input = 'my address is @@address@@ and my house is at @@street@@ and the number is  @@number@@ or so ';
    preg_match('/@@[^a-z]@@/', $input, $output);
    echo $output[0]; 
    echo $output[1];
```

Actually all my tokens are surrounded by  two @@ but the tokens can vary in number of characters and items.
Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all()` to get all matches. `preg_match()` just returns the first match.

Your regexp is wrong. `[^a-z]` matches everything *except* letters, but you want to match letters. And you need the `+` quantifier to match more than one.

```
preg_match_all('/@@[a-z]+@@/', $input, $matches);
$output = $matches[0];
var_dump($output);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/snB2LS)

Comment: ah, now I see the preg_match_ALL(!) was the important point..